# Fork damper circuit reconditioning

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, suspension

I have a rockshox Dart II from 2007. I have recently rebuilt it for the first time in 9 years as it had basically locked up, and not so surprisingly given its neglectful treatment, its still not really doing what it is supposed to. while the fork drives with significantly less stiction and reaches its travel limits, there is so much rebound, even when the adjuster is fully open, that it would probably be better suited on my car. I assume the rebound and compression have had it, but I wonder if there is a fix that doesn't involve buying a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, there isn't a non-replacement option at this point.

Partly because the Dash is a very basic shock, and thus repair becomes not cost effective compared to replacement.

Repair in this case involve replacing the damping cartridge, seals, and oil, which is basically all the internal parts if it's an air sprung model.

(A coil spring model would also have a spring side.)